# Using Bluebird Promisifyall with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I'm using mongoose with Bluebird promisifyall as follows:

```
var mongoose  = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'))
```

I want to retrieve a document from mongo using where as follows:

```js
// Gets a list of Posts
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
  Post.findAsync()
    .whereAsync({author: req.query.id})
    .execAsync()
    .then(function(entity) {
            if (entity) {
              res.status(statusCode).json({
                status_code: statusCode,
                data: entity
              });
            }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(200).json({
        status_code: statusCode,
        message: 'error occured',
        errors: err
      });
    });
};
```

But it just hangs, I'm I doing something wrong?
Would appreciate any help on using promisifyall from bluebird with mongoose, thanks :)

Comment: Mongoose will already natively return a promise without the need to pull in bluebird promises. As noted the only methods that get "promisified" are the async methods like `.findOne()` to `.findOneAsync()` and not the "helpers" which are not async such as `.where()`. In short you don't need the bluebird promises unless you specifically want "additions" such as `.spread()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` and `where` are not asynchronous, they don't take callbacks. So don't use the `…Async` variant of them - you don't expect them to return a promise, you want a mongoose query object.

Try

```
Post.find().where({author: req.query.id}).execAsync()
.then(…)
.…
```

Btw, your request does hang if `entity` is falsy, you never write a response in that case. Consider adding an `else` with a `throw new Error("no entity")`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I've got functions to handle entity not found and other such, just didn't include it here